# Home Studio Exercises/Studies?

Tags: studio, studio-lighting

I have a basic home studio setup now, and I want to get better at using it. So far I've just been shooting away at the dog, and a couple stuffed animals.

I really don't have any feel for lighting subjects with multiple lights--it's pretty much all trial and error. I'm hoping to pickup a digital lightmeter within the coming weeks, so until then I just run around, make some changes, and snap away.

This seems like the most backwards way to learn how to shoot in a studio setup.

What are some exercises, or studies that I can do that will help me get better at studio photography?

I'm interested in both still life shots, as well as single and family portraits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Strobist: Lighting 101](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/03/lighting-101.html)

You can also jump into [basic lighting setups](http://www.fotoflock.com/index.php/learn-photography/tips-tricks/29-tips-and-tricks/5571-strobist-photography-lighting-and-basic-setups) to experiment with.

Answer (score 3):

You say you've been photographing your dog somewhat dismissively, but IMO s/he would be a wonderful subject; I smell huge opportunity to make some really winning portraits of him/her. Good pet portraits are tricky, so it's a deep subject. I don't have any experience in studio lighting, so I can't help there, but if the dog is willing to hang out and be photographed over and over, I'd suggest some super high quality portraits of him/her as an initial goal.

Answer (score 3):

I second [strobist.com](http://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/03/lighting-101.html).

Also, check out this book:  [Digital Portrait Photography by Steve Sint](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1600593356?ie=UTF8&tag=ajsstuff&linkCode=as2&camp=1634&creative=19450&creativeASIN=1600593356).  It contains the best lighting primer I have come across.