# Advices for a good studio lighting photography book?

Tags: macro, studio-lighting, books, studio

I'm new to studio photography. I have at home a little studio to shoot macros and portraits. I'm equipped with strobes and a macro ring flash. I'm now looking for a beginner/intermediate studio lighting books to learn the techniques and experiment them.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Home Studio Exercises/Studies?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/home-studio-exercises-studies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not a collection of exercises, I would suggest the title "Light: Science and Magic" by Fil Hunter, Paul Fuqua, and Steven Biver.  It's a classic book that discusses how light moves around a scene to better understand difficult lighting challenges.  There are several examples to follow if you want to recreate for your own education.

Your local library may have an earlier edition to check out, too.

Answer (score 3):

I'd second the suggestion of "Light: Science and Magic" it's an outstanding technical manual for how light behaves.  If you find that kind of technical explanation too dry or to abstract you may also want to read something a little more hands on.

Scott Kelby's "Light It, Shoot It, Retouch It" is good read.  I also liked Kevin Kubotas Lighting Notebook.

Ultimately though, the best instruction is hands on.  You have the space and the equipment so you should be experimenting constantly.